# Which is the correct encoding for a degree character?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, ascii, iso-8859-1

I have a line of code that alters text

```
temperature<-as.numeric(gsub("°.*","",temp))
```

R does not like the "°" character. When I save the file it says I need to use a different encoding.

I have tried all sorts of different encodings from the list, but they all save the code in some variation of

```
temperature<-as.numeric(gsub("??.*","",temp))
```

My current solution is to open the script in notepad and copy paste the code into rstudio. Which encoding do I need to save a ° in rstudio?

Comment: The character `°` (U+00B0,  *Degree Sign*) **is defined** in `iso-8859-1`  or in `iso-8859-15` or `iso-8859-2` etc…

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be saving properly with iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full solution to this in rstudio was to go to file -> save with encoding -> select ISO-8859-1 -> check the box Set as default encoding for source files. Now the file opens properly with the degree character every time.